# Previsualizar un documento guardado en Alfresco desde mi aplicación

Tags: java, spring, alfresco

Actualmente estoy desarrollando una aplicación donde, entre otras cosas, se conecta a un Alfresco para almacenar documentos. Hasta ahí todo bien, consigo crear carpetas, subir documentos y descargarlos, ahora me gustaría poder obtener una previsualización del mismo desde el navegador (como la que implementa el propio gestor) y me gustaría saber si es posible usar el visor de Alfresco o de como podría usar otro visor en la misma.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes incrustar un documento en html mediante la etiqueta `iframe`:

```
<iframe src="/fichero.pdf&embedded=true" > </iframe>
```

Answer (score -1):

Para previsualizar documentos, Alfresco utiliza pdf.js por lo que podrías seguir un planteamiento similar, teniendo en cuenta que tendrás que implementar la generación del ticket válido para consultar el documento albergado en Alfresco (no creo que puedas invocarlo directamente con un iframe).

Por ejemplo a través de CMIS, la url podría similar a la siguiente (una vez conectado y generado el ticket válido):

> http://localhost:"+puerto+"/alfresco/guestDownload/d/workspace/SpacesStore/"
>   + idDocumentoSinVersion + "/" + nombreDocumento